# Usage of 'ever' in the following sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

Is 'ever' really necessary in the following sentence?

1- This is the first time I have (ever) been to England.

2- This is the first time I have (ever) seen a crocodile

3- This is the best goal I have (ever) seen in my life.

4- She is the most beautiful woman I have (ever) seen.

Answer (score 2):

**It is not necessary, but adds meaning**

Here, the word "ever" is being used as an [intensifier](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/intensifiers-very-at-all).